# Can I use copper tape to connect Live AC power?

Tags: cables, copper

I want to fit a light on a wall in my flat, but there's no way of getting power cables discretely to it (I can't get to it from behind the wall, and the wall's not thick enough for me to embed a cable).

Looking for ideas online, it appears that someone has used adhesive copper tape, sticking strips to the wall to get the power where needed then painting over them.

Can I do this? 
I guess I'd cover the tape with insulation tape before painting over.
If it is plausible, how thick/wide would the tape need to be to handle it?

FYI

- UK Mains voltage: 240 VAC
- Power light would use: 5-10 W

Thank you!

Lloyd

Comment: If you're going to do this - especially at that power level - feed 12V or even 5V (from a mains adapter) via the copper tapes, not 240V. And use 5V or 12V lights.

Comment: Doing this with mains voltage is a really Bad Idea. Serious fire and shock hazard.  And I'm not usually one to be a nanny.

Comment: What's the wall made out of? Paper? Presuming it's not actually that thin and has some substance to it, you can be discreet with flat twin and earth or a flat oval conduit. What you are considering doing is a lethal shock and fire hazard. Never install anything that isn't safe in the same room as an inquisitive cat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, yes. But you shouldn't. There are some drawbacks to this:

- It won't be capable of the short circuit current, you'd have to alter the fuse rating.
- It won't be properly insulated.
- Applied isolation can be easily punctured, since it isn't inside the wall or a tube.
- It won't meet any electrical building code.

I suggest that you get a 12V isolated power supply and use LED lights.
It will be a safe voltage, a low (short circuit) current and still give be able to supply 10 Watts (1 Amp).

You might need to check for the thickness of the copper tape before use. And check it is capable of the current that you will require.
I suggest that you look for flat speaker wire and use that instead of copper tape.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

A standard method is to hide your cables in pvc or you can go creative with the cables. Never use 240V with expose wire.

Comment: You forgot batteries :)

Comment: I'm lazy. Too much work to remove them and charge it.